# Define the code via: :delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

what is the purpose of using this particular code "`via: :delete`" in routes.rb?

```
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

I Know the purpose of using "`match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',`".  Please Define the code "`via: :delete`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:via option is to constrain the request to one or more HTTP methods,
look at [HTTP Verb Constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints)